# VBA excel specific cell entry and adding a warning message

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that I am trying to enter new product details in.

One column requires a 5 digit number.  What I would like my code to do is once this number is entered if it is not exactly a 5 digit number, send a warning message box asking to check the job number.

The warning message should apply if the entry is <>5 digits and also if it contains letters.  However whatever the entry I still want the cell to accept the entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I would use `Excel Data Validation`

[image]

Simply change range to be between 9999 and 100000, so it will be a 5 digit number. Or you can use a standard Excel formula to validate the entry.

At the data validation dialog you can also define an alert or error mensage.

[image]

For more information: [Excel reference on data validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Thank you Danilo Favato, is there also a way you check if there has been a duplicated number added in the same column? Thank you

Comment: @LJohnstone not with the `Data validation` feature, but you could use `Conditional formating` to highlight the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This is coded for column **B**.

Place the following in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, s As String, L As Long
    Dim addy As String
    Set rng = Intersect(Range("B:B"), Target)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each r In rng
        s = r.Text
        L = Len(s)
        addy = r.Address(0, 0)
        If L <> 5 Then
            MsgBox "Please check " & addy
        Else
            For i = 1 To 5
                If Not IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) Then
                    MsgBox "Please check " & addy
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I think I understand what the code is saying.  However I am having issues with the following line: Set rng = Intersect(Range("B:B"), Target)  I understand this is for column B but it doesn't seem to accept this.  I tried also pointing it to the cell specifically that it would be checking using 7,3 indicating row 7 column 3 but no luck.  Can you help?